# datepicker do not bind

Tags: datepicker, bind

I managed to insert a datepicker inside the detailsview. However, the dates on the details view form does not bind to the gridview like the other bound field. It is left blank when passed to Gridview. Please see code below.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="Request_ID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" Font-Size="Small" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="590px" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="400px" />
<Fields>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CS_Rep" HeaderText="CS_Rep" SortExpression="CS_Rep" >
<ControlStyle Width="200px" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date_Rcvd">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox id="Date_Rcvd" Text='<%# Eval("Date_Rcvd") %>' runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Rcvd") %>'></asp:label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Time_Rcvd" HeaderText="Time_Rcvd" SortExpression="Time_Rcvd" >
<ControlStyle Width="200px" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

//for gridview
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ``

my aspx.cs

```
aspx.cs

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```